# Is it possible to add multiple GravityForms forms to a WooCommerce product?

Tags: php, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm running the following plugins on WordPress:

- WooCommerce
- GravityForms
- WooCommerce - Gravity Forms Product Add-ons

My products are summer camp registrations. Common to all these registration forms are basic information, such as name, gender, grade, etc. The camps do differ in some ways, such as available weeks and extended daycare options.

I want to put all the "common" fields in one form, say, **Form Z**.

Then, I want to create separate forms for fields that differ per camp, *e.g.* **Form A**, **Form B**, and so on.

Finally, in the product page for one camp, I want to add **Form A** and **Form Z**, *e.g.*

```
[gravityform id="1" title="false" description="false"]
[gravityform id="3" title="false" description="false"]
```

For the next camp, **Form B** and **Form Z**, and so on.

The problem is, the first form (the camp-specific one) appears where I want it to appear—up top, next to the product image—but the second appears in a "Product Description" tab down below.

[image]

At first I thought it was because I was lacking "Product" and "Total" fields on **Form Z**, but adding these fields has made no difference. It feels like it should be perfectly possible to combine multiple Gravity Forms inside a product, to make forms modular. Why is my form appearing in the product description tab?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening.

**Both** forms were actually in the "Product Description" tab. However, the WooCommerce Gravity Forms Product Add-On plugin has a module where you can select a form...

[image]

...and that selected form gets *moved* from "Product Description" to the area up top.

I don't believe there is a way to combine multiple forms, using this method at least.